# Given an algebraic root is it always possible to find a monic polynomial with integer coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let us suppose we have some algebraic number $a$, is it always possible to find a monic polynomials with integer coefficients that has $a$ as its root? If this procedure exists, what is it called?

Comment: You're asking if there exists an Algebraic Number which is not an Algebraic Integer. The Wikipedia page on the latter gives such an example.

Comment: $a=2$ is an algebraic number, but there is no monic polynomial with integer coefficients that has $2$ as its root.

Comment: @LeeMosher You mean  $a=\frac{1}{2}$. For $a=2$ we can take $f(x)=x-2$.

Comment: Oops, that's what happens when a geometric group theorist writes about algebraic numbers.